# Xamarin Forms + Firebase - Authenticating users uid by database before allowing read/write of data

Tags: c#, firebase-realtime-database, xamarin.forms, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am starting to build another app using Xamarin Forms and Firebase for authentication and storage,
however last time I built an application it had security problems due to my lack of understanding about Firebases rules and how to authenticate a user properly.

I know how to read/write to my database, I just don't understand how to pass the Users UID from the application to the database for checking by the rules to allow them to read/write.

Database rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    "users": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid",
        ".read": "$uid === auth.uid"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

These rules are meant to check the UID passed to the database by the UID stored on the users account under database~("Person/", uid).

How can I properly authenticate my users to allow them to read/write whilst still protecting the data?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're using a package that signs in to Firebase Authentication (such as [`Xamarin.Firebase.Auth`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xamarin.Firebase.Auth/)), the `auth` variable (and its `uid` property) in your security rules are automatically set for you.

Whenever a user has signed into your application, their UID and other properties will be available in the `auth` variable in security rules. If a client is accessing the database without signing in the user, the `auth` variable will be `null`.

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for your response. Only just saw it today. I later figured this out but I honestly completely forgot I made this post. Thanks again!